# Good JS error notifier?

Tags: javascript

Is there a JS plugin / service that notifies me when users have JS errors?

I normally use Airbrake.io's JS notifier, but that only works in Ruby apps. My current app is front-end javascript only.

Comment: You would need a backend to be able to store/send you the notifications.

Comment: @epascarello With services like Airbrake you don't need a backend. This is precisely the point of this kind of services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed like a pretty clever hack; use Google Analytics. There's a writeup here:

http://www.thetaboard.com/blog/client-side-error-logging-with-google-analytics?r=378

You'll have to customize to your own app because it's by no means perfect, but at least it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Airbrake.io requires a Ruby application?

On [this page](http://help.airbrake.io/kb/troubleshooting-2/javascript-notifier) you can find:

> #### Manually inserting the JS
>
> If you are using another framework, you can manually assemble this
>   javascript to enable JS error tracking. It's important to insert it
>   right after the opening "head" tag of the HTML (ie, within the head
>   section), so that any errors that occur on the page are caught by the
>   HT JS notifier.

[Errorception](http://errorception.com/) also claims to notify javascript error.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried any of these services.